# Migrating customer password from Margento Go to community

Tags: magento, encryption, passwords, windows-ce

We are migrating our store on Magento Go to community edition, due the former shutting down in Feb 2015.

The product import and basic customer customer info imported fine, but when customers try to login to their accounts magento tells them the password is incorrect.

Magento Go support explains this as different encryption algorithms used in go and community edition, but  they also said it is possible to change the way password are decrypted/encrypted in magento ce?

Wonder if anyone has any thoughst on that?

p.s.  we can ask all 1000s of customers to reset their passwords, but this wont look like a seemless migration for them.

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting guide over here regarding the downgrade from Enterprise Edition to Community Edition which addresses the different hashing mechanisms.

[Downgrading Magento Enterprise to Community](http://blog.yanted.com/2014/02/21/downgrading-magento-enterprise-to-community/)

Take a look at the file  app/code/core/Enterprise/Pci/Model/Encryption.php . It contains the algorithm used by the enterprise version. So all you have to do is to create your own model and replicate the behavior. After that, tell Magento about the rewrite:

```
<helpers>
    <core>
         <encryption_model>Module_Namespace_Model_Encryption</encryption_model>
    </core>
</helpers>
```

With that in place both frontend and backend login should work as before, no need to change passwords or anything.

You'll need to apply this for your instance of Magento GO instead of Enterprise, but the functionality in the end should essentially be the same.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply and that's a great article! unfortunately magento go does not provide ftp or ssh access to the source code, and their support can not disclose any code either. They said go is based on CE and EE version and they are not sure what version exactly, however they do know it's a SHA256 encryption.

Comment: Pretty typical with Magento. They killed the Go platform which was derived from EE code, but because EE isn't free, they won't give you the code necessary for modification to make CE use the EE password encryption algorithm. Which means you need to find a developer who works with EE and will hack together a module for you. Yet another bad taste left by Magento GOne.

Comment: I think would be easier to kindly ask customers to reset their passwords.  Thanks for your replies though